# What do I have to do to get RenderSize?

Tags: c#, wpf

I would think I could check an image's `RenderSize` once I set its `Source` but apparently something else needs to happen first. So for example, if I call

```
MainImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imagePath));
var zoomNeeded = Math.Max((border.ActualWidth / MainImage.RenderSize.Width) - 1.0, (border.ActualHeight / MainImage.RenderSize.Height)-1.0);
```

then `MainImage.RenderSize.Width` is 0 (if I had no image loaded previously). I've tried putting `MainImage.Source.Freeze();` in between those lines but it didn't help. I'm guessing WPF does the actual load on another thread, so is there any way to get that thread so I can wait for it?

Comment: You may try to set the `CacheOption` of the BitmapImage to `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad`. If that won't work, you can also load the BitmapImage from a previously downloaded Stream by setting its `StreamSource` property. Or get the size in a handler of the `BitmapImage.DownloadCompleted` event.

Comment: Good ideas, but it still showed me 0's when the `CacheOption` was `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad`, and (presumably since I'm loading from a disk) the `BitmapImage.DownloadCompleted` event was never fired.

Comment: Use the BitmapImage's Width and Height instead of the Image control's RenderSize?

Comment: I'm seeing NaN in both of those values. I'm guessing because they're not set in the designer.

Comment: I mean the BitmapImage, not the Image control.

Comment: Oh my mistake, sorry. I'm seeing values and I don't know what they correspond to. I'm seeing 911.36 by 1372.16 when I loaded an image that's 2848 by 4288

Comment: That's certainly because the bitmap has something like 300 dpi. You can also get a `PixelWidth` and `PixelHeight` from the BitmapImage. Besides that, the size of the Image control would only be equal to the size of the Source bitmap if its Stretch property is set to None. Maybe you can just handle the Image control's `SizeChanged` event.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111763/discussion-between-adam-r-grey-and-clemens).